# Add product image in new order email

Tags: order-email

I want to add a product image in the new order email template. 
How can I do this?
I am using my custom template and I want product image also.
so how can I take an image on my custom template
The custom template I have created from,

```
system->configuration->transnational emails
```

Comment: Please view link ! http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/138348/34916
Hope to help you!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

1. **First Step**

Edit the file: `app/design/frontend/YOUR_PACKAGE/YOUR_THEME/template/email/order/items.phtml`

After this line:

```
<th align="left" bgcolor="#EAEAEA" style="font-size:13px; padding:3px 9px"> <?php echo $this->__('Sku') ?></th>
```

Add this:

```
<th align="left" bgcolor="#EAEAEA" style="font-size:13px; padding:3px 9px"><?php echo $this->__('Image') ?></th>
```

2. **Second Step**

Edit the file: `app/design/frontend/YOUR_PACKAGE/YOUR_THEME/template/email/order/items/order/default.phtml`

> **Note:** If this file doesn't exist in your package then you can find this file from base package (`app/design/frontend/base/default/template/email/order/items/order/default.phtml`)

After this line:

```
<td align="left" valign="top" style="font-size:11px; padding:3px 9px; border-bottom:1px dotted #CCCCCC;"><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getSku($_item)) ?></td>
```

Add this:

```
<img src="<?php echo Mage::getModel('catalog/product_media_config')  
                ->getMediaUrl($_product->getThumbnail()); ?>"  width="135" height="135" alt="<?php echo $_item->getName() ?>" />
```

---

***EDIT***

---

For configurable product parent image display :

Edit the file `app/design/frontend/YOUR_PACKAGE/YOUR_THEME/template/email/order/items/order/default.phtml`

After this line:

```
<?php $_order = $this->getItem()->getOrder() ?>
```

Add this:

```
<?php 

if ($_item->getProductType() == Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type::TYPE_CONFIGURABLE) {
    $parentId = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_type_configurable')
                       ->getParentIdsByChild($_item->getProductId());  
    $_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')  
                       ->setStoreId($_item->getOrder()->getStoreId())  
                       ->load($parentId);
} else {
    $_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')  
                       ->setStoreId($_item->getOrder()->getStoreId())  
                       ->load($_item->getProductId());  
}

?>
```

Then, if not already done, after this line:

```
<td align="left" valign="top" style="font-size:11px; padding:3px 9px; border-bottom:1px dotted #CCCCCC;"><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getSku($_item)) ?></td>
```

Add this line:

```
<img src="<?php echo Mage::getModel('catalog/product_media_config')  
                ->getMediaUrl($_product->getThumbnail()); ?>"  width="135" height="135" alt="<?php echo $_item->getName() ?>" />
```

Comment: glad to help you@sipl

Comment: Wow, nice, it works very good!
I have only a little problem: if a have a configurable product, how can i show only the image of configurable product, without the images of sub-items? Thansk!

Comment: Check my edit @Simbus82

Answer (score 1):

(Magento 2 get Product Image By ID in Order)

Please follow code after:

```
$_item = $block->getItem();

$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();

$_product = $objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($_item->getProductId());

$imageHelper  = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image');

$image_url = $imageHelper->init($_product, 'product_page_image_small')->setImageFile($_product->getImage())->resize(100, 100)->getUrl();
```

100% success :) !
Please view [link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/138348/34916) ! Hope to help you!

Answer (score 1):

my solution example:

> email/order/items/order/default.phtml

after line `<?php $_order = $this->getItem()->getOrder() ?>` insert:

```
<?php
if ($_item->getProductType() == Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type::TYPE_CONFIGURABLE) {
    $_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku',$_item->getSku());
    $_product_image = (string) Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'thumbnail')->resize(30);

} else {
    $_product = $_item->getProduct();
    $_product_image = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_media_config')->getMediaUrl($_product->getThumbnail());
}
?>
```

and somewhere insert something like this:

```
<p class="product-name"><img src="<?php echo $_product_image; ?>"  width="35" height="35" alt="<?php echo $_item->getName() ?>" /><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_item->getName()) ?></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$_productThumbnail = '';

if ($_item->getProductType() == Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type::TYPE_CONFIGURABLE && count($_item->getChildrenItems()) > 0) {
    $_productThumbnail = $_item->getChildrenItems()[0]->getProduct()->getThumbnail();
}

if ($_productThumbnail == '' || $_productThumbnail == 'no_selection')
{
    $_productThumbnail = $_item->getProduct()->getThumbnail();
}
```

> And then

```
<img src="<?php echo Mage::getModel('catalog/product_media_config')  
                ->getMediaUrl($_productThumbnail ); ?>"  width="135" height="135" alt="<?php echo $_item->getName() ?>" />
```