# Magento 1.8 Order mail product image not appear

Tags: magento-1.8, orders, email, product-images

Am using `Magento 1.8` here i want to send product image in order email.
I refer this link [Add product image in new order email](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/75864/add-product-image-in-new-order-email).

this is the code:

`app/design/frontend/base/default/template/email/order/items/order/default.phtml`

**default.phtml**

```
<?php 

if ($_item->getProductType() == Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type::TYPE_CONFIGURABLE) {
    $parentId = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_type_configurable')
                       ->getParentIdsByChild($_item->getProductId());  
    $_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')  
                       ->setStoreId($_item->getOrder()->getStoreId())  
                       ->load($parentId);
} else {
    $_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')  
                       ->setStoreId($_item->getOrder()->getStoreId())  
                       ->load($_item->getProductId());  
}

?>
```

And here am showing image

```
<td align="left" valign="top" style="font-size:11px; padding:3px 9px; border-bottom:1px dotted #CCCCCC;">
      <img src="<?php echo Mage::getModel('catalog/product_media_config')->getMediaUrl($_product->getThumbnail()); ?>" width="135" height="135" alt="<?php echo $_item->getName() ?>" />
</td>
```

But i got mail like this

[image]

> Its not working for simple, configurable and bundle product also

How can i fix this error?

> **Note:** This question already asked but am not get the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think the reason for product showing wrong image is this function written in

```
app/design/frontend/base/default/template/email/order/items/order/default.phtml
```

The mentioned code, checks for configurable product and then tries to get its parent ids. It should be the other way round. Check this edited code:

```
if ($_item->getProductType() !== Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type::TYPE_CONFIGURABLE) {
    $parentIds = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_type_configurable')
                       ->getParentIdsByChild($_item->getProductId());  
    $_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')  
                       ->setStoreId($_item->getOrder()->getStoreId())  
                       ->load($parentIds[0]);
} else {
    $_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')  
                       ->setStoreId($_item->getOrder()->getStoreId())  
                       ->load($_item->getProductId());  
}
```

For information please visit following URLs:-

[New order email missing product image {{layout handle="sales_email_order_items" order=$order}}](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/165940/new-order-email-missing-product-image-layout-handle-sales-email-order-items)

[Add product image in new order email](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/75864/add-product-image-in-new-order-email)

I hope this is helpful for you.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I tried your code, I got the same error.  And i checked that image `url` in gmail. This is the `url`  `https://ci6.googleusercontent.com/proxy/ng51G6Tb9l9E1eg2PtEvgGZgr0jK9ur_pZ7vrJYk3uUIBqJRvB5AxeL8ZzAGi773v79Tgi1xFhfuf9uWq78zQ0eXYdOhsUFDfVkQp7rSb2ka=s0-d-e1-ft#http://127.0.0.1/ramesh/my_store/media/catalog/product/`

Comment: Try this You can use getSmallImage(), getThumbnail() for different images of the product.

Please visit this URL:- https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/75873/52231